# How to increase a soft limit of a stack size for processes run by some user (uid) on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris-10

Our enterprise runs on Oracle Tuxedo 10, under Solaris 10. As a result of some recent development (customization source code all across the system was changed by extending sizes of local variables which are declared in C functions) we run into Stack Overflow problem from time to time (depending on how long the functions calls chain is).
As a work-around we decided on increasing a soft limit size of a stack (for all Tuxedo processes running by single user). Considering to use ulimit, /etc/project etc. 
Clear & short step-by-step instruction for our on-site support team on how to extend a stack size (per-user) in Solaris 10 would be very appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use limit -s

Then you can apply it to /etc/.login or /etc/profile 
limit -s 8192 would apply 8192 kbytes to all users on the system if you stick it in one of these 2 files.

For a specific user, use projects or add limit -s  to .bash_profile of your user.

This would affect every sessions connecting as that user.